# How can I make class diagram from the database diagram?

Tags: mysql, class, class-diagram, database-diagram

![Database diagram of my online shopping store][1]

```
brands
Column
brand_id    
brand_title

table cart
Column
cart_id 
p_id    
ip_add  
customer_id 
qty 

categories
Column  
cat_id
cat_title

customers
Column
customer_id
customer_name
customer_email  
customer_pass
customer_country
customer_city
customer_contact
customer_address
customer_image
customer_ip 

customer_orders
Column  
order_id    
customer_id 
due_amount  
invoice_no  
total_products  
order_date
order_status

payments
Column  
payment_id
invoice_no
amount
payment_mode
ref_no  
code
payment_date    

pending_orders
Column  T
order_id    
customer_id 
invoice_no
product_id  
qty 
order_status

products
Column  
product_id  
cat_id  
brand_id        
date
product_title
product_img1    
product_img2    
product_img3    
product_price   
product_desc    
product_keywords    
status  

admins
Column  
admin_id    
admin_email
admin_pass
```

I have these all tables of my database. I want to make a class diagram. connectivity of all tables in image if you required (I could not attach it). Admin not connected. because this table not used as foreign key in any other table. and payment table is not connected. Because payments is only added here for show the payment that have done. 
I am really very very worried about that. I need class diagram. it is headache for me. I am person who can do coding, but cannot make diagrams. I need help in class diagram.

Comment: Do you want fries with your ER model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make ER diagram using the **Reverse Engineering** functionality of MySQL workbench.
You just need to follow few simple steps:

Ctrl+R and then next till Finish.

Attaching an image for your reference.[image]